# WIAScanner class is scanning only in flatbed. Device properties are null...What is wrong?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wia, thread-synchronization

I am using this existing class from http://miljenkobarbir.com/using-a-scanner-without-dialogs-in-net/
and it is not working at all. It scans from the flatbed when it is supposed to scan from the document feeder. The only thing that works is that it detects my device which is wireless by the way but the device properties are null. No exception gets thrown.

P.S I am calling the Scan method from another thread not the UI thread but I used a lock like this below

```
List<Image> images = null;
lock(this)
{
    images = WIAScanner.Scan("deviceID"); // This gets called but does not return back to control
}
```